# JSF <h:outputText ...> that binds to a bean inside table> need ajax support

Tags: java, jsf

I have a table of which one column is used for heavy computing (= long time to wait).

I would like to add Ajax support to my page so that the table will be displayed incomplete and the data for this particular column will be added by Ajax after a few seconds.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant (view) code?

Answer (score 0):

You need push or similar technology for this. Have a look at [icepush](http://www.icepush.org/), primefaces [poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/poll.jsf). Richfaces offers something close as well.

UPDATE: To achieve this with some javascript only you can issue an ajax update after the page is rendered. This would be something like:

```
$(function() {
  var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents")
  event.initEvent("click", true, true)
  jsf.ajax.request(document.getElementById("my-form:my-command-link"), event, {render: "myTableId"})
})
```

where my-command-link refers to a h:commandLink inside form with id my-form. This commandLink should have an action attached which will populate missing data. Of course you can hide the command link with css. The result would be an initial page with empty table and ajax update fetching missing date processing in the background.

I am not 100% sure about event initialization in this example, you may need to fine tune this yourself but I have used jsf.ajax.request this way already with success.

Comment: Hi , it looks  o.k BUT how do i stop polling after that i have all the data in the table ? thanks

Comment: Primefaces poll can be stopped with its api, explore examples more. I am not sure about icepush, usually you don't stop it, it just hangs waiting for server broadcast that may not come.

Comment: Hi , is there another way to do this ? i need an event that will triger the ajax function to fetch the data. An event like onAfterLoad. Thanks

Comment: @user1082094 I have posted another solution based on jsf ajax api only. Maybe this will suit your requirements better.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use a ajax support in h:inputText then here is on example

**in XHTML File**

```
  <h:inputText style=" width : 70px;" id="dempID"
        value="#{InformationLoan.instance.Code}">
        <a:support event="onchange" limitToList="true" reRender="nameID"  // form ID i haved use here.
        action="#{InformationController.codeValue(InformationLoan.instance.Code)}"/>
  </h:inputText>
```

**in Bean File**

```
public void codeValue(String value){
    try{

        info("HERE IS YOUR VALUE : " + value);
        // TYPE YOUR CODE......

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , i need ajax event on h:outputText in a table .